# Iterate through Table of Contents in docx using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a doc with a table of contents that was auto generated in the beginning of the doc and would like to parse through this table of contents. Is this possible using **python-docx**? If I try to iterate through `doc.paragraphs.text`, the text in that is in the table of contents does not show up.

I tried the following: iterating through paragraphs and checking for the `paragraph.style.name` being `toc 1` Then I know that I am in a ToC. But I am unable to get the actual text. I tried this:

```
if para.style.name == "toc 1" #then print para.text.
```

But `para.text` is giving me a blank string. Why would this be the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll find that the actual generated contents of the TOC is "wrapped" in a non-paragraph element. `python-docx` won't get you there directly as it only finds paragraphs that are direct children of the `w:document/w:body` element.

To get at these you'll need to go down to the lxml level, using python-docx to get you as close as possible. You can get to (and print) the body element with this:

```
document = Document('my-doc.docx')
body_element = document._body._body
print(body_element.xml)  # this will be big if your document is
```

From there you can identify the specific XML location of the parts you want and use lxml/XPath to access them. Then you can wrap them in python-docx `Paragraph` objects for ready access:

```
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

ps = body_element.xpath('./w:something/w:something_child/w:p'
paragraphs = [Paragraph(p, None) for p in ps]
```

This is not an exact recipe and will require some research on your part to work out what `w:something` etc. are, but if you want it bad enough to surmount those hurdles, this approach will work.

Once you get it working, posting your exact solution may be of help to others on search.

Comment: I began to try this out with your tips but when I see the xml file, I only see the name of the section, not the number. For example, If the table of contents has an entry: 2.3.4 Intro.......5, I see "Intro" but not 2.3.4. Do you know why that would be? I would really like the number and the text. (this is an auto generated ToC, not sure if that makes a difference.) Thanks

Comment: I would have to see the whole TOC XML block, maybe you can post it in a Gist or something. But I expect that Word is calculating those numbers based on the style or numbering properties and doesn't record them in the XML to avoid redundancy (and consequently the need to keep the two in sync).

Comment: I made a Gist which includes the xml block. It is at: https://gist.github.com/sendeb/128651f1d13e6156fe741b25488ddcb3. For example, if you look at the section that says "Introduction" I would like to see "1 Introduction" etc. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually, now that I take a look at it again, I see what you mean. The number associated with each section title is located in a different place than the section title itself.

Comment: Okay, yes, I see that the section numbers (like 1.3.1) *are* actually there, just in a prior run, separated by a tab and other bits. In the XML you gisted, there is no "container" element, meaning these paragraphs should appear in Document.paragraphs. Then you could filter on the style starting with 'TOC' and then sort through the runs for the text you want. I expect you'll find the pieces like number and title at the same run index in each paragraph, like para.runs[0], para.runs[2]. Let us know how you get on :) Don't forget to vote up the answer if it's useful to you and accept it if correct

Comment: So I gave that a try, where I am filtering out by style. But if I print para.runs the list seems to be empty. Do you know why that would be the case? this is my pseudo code: for para in doc.paragraphs: if style == "toc" print p.runs. Did I miss something? thank you!

Comment: Ah, interesting, the runs are wrapped in a w:hyperlink. So you'd need to do something like this: rs = paragraph._p.xpath('.//w:r'); for r in rs:print(Run(r, paragraph).text)

Comment: Glad to hear it, make sure you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Since most of the solution is hidden in the comment section and it took me a while to figure out exactly what the OP did and how scanny's answer changed what he was doing, I'll just post my solution here, which is only what is written in the comment section of scanny's answer. I don't fully comprehend, how the code works, so if somebody wants to edit my answer, please feel free to do so.

```
#open docx file with python-docx
document = docx.Document("path\to\file.docx")
#extract body elements
body_elements = document._body._body
#extract those wrapped in <w:r> tag
rs = body_elements.xpath('.//w:r')
#check if style is hyperlink (toc)
table_of_content = [r.text for r in rs if r.style == "Hyperlink"]
```

table_of_content will be a list, comprised of first the numbering as an item, followed by the title.