# Parse HTML file and store the headings <h1> and subheading <h2> and the text contains under them in an other file directory (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-docx

So I have this long HTML page. I actually converted my .docx document to HTML because I want all of the headings and it's the subheading to be stored in individual files because later I would want to reproduce the same file (but deleting some content or so) so my idea is that I will parse the HTML one time and store all it's headings and subheadings one time and as the requirement, I will fetch only the ones that are needed.

Could someone guide me on which library to use or is there an easier and smarter way that I may be unaware of? Please guide me.

Thanks a lot.

An example can be seen as:

```
`1    INTRODUCTION

      1.1  Purpose
           Some text for purposes

      1.2  Terminology
            Some text for Terminology

2    TESTING

      2.1  Dependencies
           Some text some text some text

     2.2  Testing Components
           Some text some text some text

     2.3   Test Architecture
           Some text some text some text
```

and I want them to saved in different folders like with all the text stored in these folders. Just literally copy and paste but maintaining the proper folder and all the HTML content.

```
  `/home/user/Projects/HTML_Parser
     ├── main.py/
     │   ├── __init__.py
     │   ├── db.py
     │   ├── schema.sql
     │   ├── auth.py
     │   ├── blog.py
     │   ├── templates/
     │   └── static/
     │       └── style.css
     ├── 1.INTRODUCTION/
     │   ├── 1.1Purpose
     │   └── 1.2Terminology
     └── 2.TESTING
     │   ├── 2.1Dependencies
     │   └── 2.2TestingComponents
     └── 2.3TestArchitecture `
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that converting a docx to html is not the right approach for extracting the headings and sub-headings from my experience. Since we are dealing with unstructured documents(`.docx`) authored by different authors, there is no specific or defined way of identifying a sub-heading under a heading unless the author explicitly defines it as a sub-heading while creating the document.

In some cases, authors might choose to define a heading as a `Normal` formatting and `Bold` it instead of defining it as a `Heading`, and in some cases, an author might choose to define it as an `Heading` itself.

So, to keep it short, you will be able to identify headings and sub-headings only if the author has done proper formatting of them while creating the document. I have come across many cases where such formatting is not done **e.g.** `Heading` might be created by the author as `Heading` type whereas the sub-heading would be a `Normal` type with `Bold` applied to it. Hence you will be able to find headings and sub-headings only if there is a proper formatting like the size of sub-headings are smaller than the headings in all cases.

Even for such cases, I would recommend using `python-docx` package directly on the `.docx` itself since it can extract the headings and sub-headings if they are defined with proper formatting by the author.

This [recipe](https://github.com/kmrambo/Python-docx-Reading-paragraphs-tables-and-images-in-document-order-) will help you extract all the information from a `.docx` including tables, images and texts (along with style information). You can use this piece of code to extract text(headings and sub-headings) alone from this.

-> After reading all this, if you're still inclined towards extracting information from html version of the docx, then the best package to use is `beautifulsoup` for parsing html files and extracting content from it. You can find sample answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716272/how-to-extract-h1-tag-text-with-beautifulsoup).

**Update:**
As I see, since your documents have Table of Content(ToC), you can directly extract the ToC either from the html or from the docx and do some structuring after the extractions. This is the best way I could think of.

1. For extracting ToC from html, you can use `Beautifulsoup` to extract the portion of ToC from html and then structure the extractions
2. For extracting ToC from docx, you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210905/iterate-through-table-of-contents-in-docx-using-python-docx/55687092)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, Karthick for your reply but in my case I am working of professionally edited documents (more like templates) so I need to store the text under the the <h1> tag. An example of it is here:

2    INTRODUCTION

      2.1      Purpose
                 

      2.2      Terminology

3    TESTING CASES


    3.1      Dependencies

    3.2      Testing Components

    3.3      Test Architecture

Comment: In that case you can go for ```Beautifulsoup``` as suggested in the end of answer

Comment: I added the proper hierarchy in my actual question too just so that everyone can understand better of what my needs are.

Comment: @NabihaRaza Do your documents have Table of Contents?

Comment: Yes it does actually. @Karthick

Comment: @NabihaRaza Updated the answer